# what is math for uniswap calculates the amountout and amountin why 997 and 1000

Tags: tokens, uniswap, fees, defi, decentralized-exchange

```
function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {//the amount of user,amount in pool,output token amount in pool
    require(amountIn > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
    require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
    uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(997);
    uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
    uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
    amountOut = numerator / denominator;//getting the output amount amount we will get 
}

// given an output amount of an asset and pair reserves, returns a required input amount of the other asset
function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountIn) {
    require(amountOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
    require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
    uint numerator = reserveIn.mul(amountOut).mul(1000);
    uint denominator = reserveOut.sub(amountOut).mul(997);
    amountIn = (numerator / denominator).add(1);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As Uniswap's fees are 0.3%, the constants 997 and 1000 are corresponding nominators and denominators to help calculate this.

```
3 / 1000 = 0.003 = 0.3%
```

Answer (score 1):

before swap `A * B = K` where **A = reserveIn B = reserveOut**

after swap `A' * B' = K` where only **k is a constant value**

**getAmountOut**

```
A' = A + 0.997 * amountIn  # here 0.3% is deducted
B' = B - amountOut
amountOut = B - B' # where A' * B' still is k
          = B - K/(A + 0.997 * amountIn)
          = B - AB/(A + 0.997 * amountIn) 
          = (B * A + B * 0.997 * amountIn - AB)/(A + 0.997 * amountIn)
          = B * 0.997 * amountIn / (A + 0.997 * amountIn)
          = B * 997 * amountIn / (1000 * A + 997 * amountIn)
```

**getAmountIn**

```
B' = B - amountOut
A' = A + 0.997 * amountIn  # here 0.3% is deducted
amountIn = (A' - A) / 0.997
         = (K/(B - amountOut) - A) / 0.997
         = (AB/(B - amountOut) - A) / 0.997
         = (A * B - A * B + A * amountOut) / (B - amountOut) / 0.997
         = A * amountOut / (B - amountOut) / 0.997
         = A * amountOut * 1000 / (B - amountOut) * 997
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my article titled [How to Handle Uniswap Withdrawals like an OG](https://medium.com/coinmonks/handle-uniswap-withdrawals-like-an-og-389fe74be18c)

Exact math is such:
[image]