# Can someone explain Uniswap's v2 getAmountIn?

Tags: uniswap, amm

Code can be seen here: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UniswapV2Library.sol#L53

What I don't understand is that if you use the constant product formula, you arrive at a different formula:

- invariant formula: resIn * resOut = k
- therefore, (resIn+amountIn)*(resOut-amountOut)=k
- solving for amountIn, we get amountIn = (resIn*resOut) / (resOut-amountOut) - resIn
- But the contract has a version that's not equivalent, even after accounting for fees.

Note: the above doesn’t include fees

```
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountIn) {
        require(amountOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint numerator = reserveIn.mul(amountOut).mul(1000);
        uint denominator = reserveOut.sub(amountOut).mul(997);
        amountIn = (numerator / denominator).add(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this calculation for the version of the contract:

[what is math for uniswap calculates the amountout and amountin why 997 and 1000](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101629/what-is-math-for-uniswap-calculates-the-amountout-and-amountin-why-997-and-1000)

In addition, the contract's version also added +1 `.add(1)` to round up as Uniswap pool strictly enforces k and make you pay one more wei to the LPs:

https://www.reddit.com/r/UniSwap/comments/rjzkcj/why_does_it_have_add1_uniswapv2library_getamountin/

Comment: sweet. Thanks so much for the answer. I see it was because once you take the fees into account the math slightly changes